# How to Get DropDown Selected Value and This Value Add in List

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

`DropDownList` Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.EmpID, 
        new SelectList(Model.EmployeeList(), "Value", "Text", Model.EmpID), 
        new { @class = "form-control" }
    )
</div>
```

`jQuery` for `DropDownList`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#EmpID").change(function () {
            var item = $("#EmpID option:selected").text();
            alert(item)
            $(".test").append(item);
            $("#EmpID").remove(item);
        });
    });
</script>
```

`EmployeeList` for `DropDown`:

```
public List<SelectListItem> EmployeeList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ProjectList = mp.EmployeeMasters.Select(o => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = o.Firstname +" "+ o.Lastname,
        Value = o.EmpID
    }).ToList();
    return ProjectList;
}
```

Whenever I select `dropdown` value and append this value and remove from `DrodownList`, but this is not working on this code.

Comment: You are removing text stored in `item`. Do you need to remove `$("#EmpID option:selected")`?

Comment: Side note: change your veiw code to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmpID, Model.EmployeeList(), new { @class = "form-control" })` (creating a 2nd identical `SelectList` from the 1st one is pointless)

Comment: I don't know where is store text..

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('option:selected', this).remove();` insetead of your `$("#EmpID").remove(item);`

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/q5u5aqqL/).